# Javascript - Change div content with onclick

Tags: javascript

i need help about changing content with onclick function.

I got a table that contains 3 links like below ;

```
<table class="galerimenu" name="gallerytype">
    <tr>
        <td ><a href="#" class="tattoo">Tattoo</a></td>
        <td ><a href="#" class="piercing">Piercing</a></td>
        <td ><a href="#" class="makeup">Makeup</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


The content that i need to call is a thumbnail gallery in div like ;

<div class="banner" id="tattoo">
    <ul>
         <li>
            <ul id='da-thumbs' class='active-da-thumbs da-thumbs'>
                <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  </div>

<div class="banner" id="piercing" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
         <li>
            <ul id='da-thumbs' class='active-da-thumbs da-thumbs'>
                <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  </div>

<div class="banner" id="makeup" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
         <li>
            <ul id='da-thumbs' class='active-da-thumbs da-thumbs'>
                <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
                 <li>
                  <a class="swipebox" data-title="Image Title" href="demo/1.jpg">
                  <img src="demo/1.jpg" alt="image" /></a>
                 </li>
    </ul>
      </li>
  </div>
```

I know that piercing and tattoo div need to be displayed as none on start. Need a simple js to call and hide that 3 divs. Thanks for help!

Js code is ;

```
 $(function() {
        $('#gallerytype').change(function(){
            $('.banner').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Help with...? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i forget to put js code. Now edited it. Can you check again please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.tattoo').click(function () {
    $('.banner').hide();
    $('#tattoo').show();
});
$('.piercing').click(function () {
    $('.banner').hide();
    $('#piercing').show();
});
$('.makeup').click(function () {
    $('.banner').hide();
    $('#makeup').show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zhwn6d1e/)**

Comment: Thats what i was looking mate. Thanks a lot. It is not working on my page , probably some js code crashes but i ll try to fix it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work:

```
$('a.tattoo').click( function() {
    $('#tattoo').toggle();
});
```